# python pyplot.quiver: Scaling of two superimposed vector fields

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scaling, vector-graphics

I want to plot two vector fields in one quiver plot. This is already working: For each point, there are two vectors in different colors. Now the problem is, that the scaling is not the same: e.g.  vector (1,0) from the first field  (`sol`) is displayed with another length as the (1,0) from field two (`res`).

How can I make quiver to plot both fields with the same scale, so that (1,0) from `res` has the same physical length on my plot as (1,0) from `sol`?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#res and sol are two vector fields with dimension (ny, nx ,2)

step=3 #not all vectors should be plotted. Just every third one (in x and y direction)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,nx,step), np.arange(0,ny,step))            
Q=plt.quiver(X,Y,sol[::step,::step,0], sol[::step,::step,1], color='r')    
W=plt.quiver(X,Y,res[::step,::step,0], res[::step,::step,1], color='b')
plt.quiverkey(Q, 0.4, 0.15, 1, r'text1', labelpos='S')
plt.quiverkey(W, 0.6, 0.15, 1, r'text2', labelpos='S')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you make it more clear? There are undefined values in your code snippet (self.field_size_x, self.field_size_y, step, sol and res). Moreover, the arange function has options for stepping (arange(self.field_size_x)[::step] and arange(0,self.field_size_x,2) are identical).

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions:

1. Normalize the input data and scale it
2. Tell quiver how to scale your data

Solution 2 (fastest):

```
Q=plt.quiver(X,Y,sol[::step,::step,0], sol[::step,::step,1], color='r', scale=1)
W=plt.quiver(X,Y,res[::step,::step,0], res[::step,::step,1], color='b', scale=1)
```

You may adjust the scale value, but you have to keep the same values in both quivers in order to get what you expect. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911439/matplotlib-quiver-scale) helped but in your case I think it's not an overspecification to give the same scale to each quiver.